# python: make websocket connection to elevenlabs with websocket-client

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, stream, connection

In elevenlabs you can now use the stream feature also with input stream. However, a socket connection must be established for this.

Unfortunately I have to implement the websocket connection myself instead of using the elevenlabs python client, because i have to use the websocket-client library and the elevenlabs client is using a different websocket library.

The problem is, however, that

`data = json.loads(ws.recv())`

blocks forever and nothing ever seems to arrive. what did I do wrong?

here is my code(BOS and EOS are exactly the same as in the documentations code of elevenlabs python client and rest of it is also nearly the same code):

```
with closing(create_connection(url, header={"xi-api-key":"mykey")) as ws:
                 
                # Send beginning of stream
                ws.send(BOS)

                # Stream text chunks and receive audio
                for text_chunk in text_chunker(text):
                    data = dict(text=text_chunk, try_trigger_generation=True)
                    ws.send(json.dumps(data))
                    try:
                        data = json.loads(ws.recv()) -> blocking here, never gets over it
                        if data["audio"]:
                            yield base64.b64decode(data["audio"])  # type: ignore
                    except TimeoutError:
                        pass

                # Send end of stream
                ws.send(EOS)

                # Receive remaining audio
                while True:
                    try:
                        data = json.loads(ws.recv())
                        if data["audio"]:
                            yield base64.b64decode(data["audio"])  # type: ignore
                    except ws.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                        break
```

with the original code from the elevenlabs client , which uses the websockets.sync.client library, it works as expected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found a solution by using WebSocketApp in a thread.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).